# PHP fopen() with command line

Tags: php, command-line-interface, fopen

ANSWER I WENT WITH BELOW!

So I have a PHP script that works prefect via the web. I would like to set it up on a scheduled task on the server that is running the web hosting. It is a windows 2008 R2 server. I seems to run fine minus the fact it won't make the output files. Do I need to have the full path name? Ex C:\logs.... or will below work? I would like to keep the script working both in web and command line.

```
$File3 = "" . $log_dir . "/" . date('m-d-Y') . ".txt"; 
$Handle3 = fopen($File3, 'a+');

$Data3 = "blah";
fwrite($Handle3, $Data3);
```

more info:

here are the errors from the log file:

fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Websites\wordpress\win\import.php on line 686

PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(bins/bins-10-09-2013.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Websites\wordpress\win\import.php on line 692

PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Websites\wordpress\win\import.php on line 699

PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Websites\wordpress\win\import.php on line 709

**WORKING!! Well, this is what I went with and it seems to work prefect.**

```
$File = "" . $uploads_dir . "/import-" . date('m-d-Y-g-ia') . ".txt";
$Handle = fopen($file1, 'a+');
if ( $Handle === false ) {
    $File = "C:\Websites\wordpress\win\\".$uploads_dir."\import-"  . date('m-d-Y-g-ia') . ".txt";
    $Handle = fopen($File, 'a+');
}
```

This way I can Use the php script both via web and on a scheduled task via windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems fopen is failing to open the file . Make sure the file is successfully opened :

```
$Handle3 = fopen($File3, 'a+');

if( $Handle3 === false ) echo 'Unable to open file';
```

If it fails , check below items one at a time :

- Check file / folder permissions .
- Check with different slashes `"/"` , `"\"` in the path .
- Check if it works with absolute path ( full path ) .
- Check by changing directory before `fopen` : `chdir('path\to\php\script')`
- etc .

If the issue is with the path , one way make it work both cases is :

```
//  First try with the path that works from web
$File3 = "" . $log_dir . "/" . date('m-d-Y') . ".txt"; 

$Handle3 = fopen( $File3, 'a+' );

if( $Handle3 === false )
{
//  It failed so may be scheduled task invoked the script
//  So use the path that works in invoked by scheduled task
    $File3 = "path\that\works\from\command\line"; 
    $Handle3 = fopen( $File3 ,'a+' );
}
if( $Handle3 === false )
{
    echo 'Failed to open file';
    exit;
}
else
{
//  What ever
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the route I went. Edited org question.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the full url for an fopen or fwrite.  These are the things I would look at first:

- What is the output when you echo $log_dir?

  - Does the directory exist?
- Are permissions set correctly?
- If you create the file before running the script, does it then successfully write to the file?
- What is the value of $Handle3 after the fopen?
- What is the return value of the fwrite that you call on the last line?
- Is error handling set to all? (it should be for debugging)